# IndustrialCraft: Good early power system

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-industrialcraft, minecraft-mods

In Feed The Beast there are a lot of mods (as we all know) and one of them is IndustrialCraft (talking about v2 with the gregtech extention) is probably the most difficult one in the game to get started with.

After doing some mining and getting around 5 stacks of iron, 3 stacks of copper, 3 stacks of tin, half a stack of gold, 18 diamonds and 2 emeralds I figured it was time to get started. I just don't know what to do first. I figured energy(EU) it the way to go but i am in a massive desert so I can't use watermills. I don't know any other easy-to-setup energy sources. except solar panels, which require energy to make.

I also thought of a generator but I am low on wood and coal I need to use for cooking things and torches of course.

I might get into windmills but they are so ugly hanging up there in the sky.

Are there any other ways to get energy(EU)?

Comment: If you just got 5 stacks of iron (either ore or bars) and much more goodies you should at least have an abundance of coal. Its not hard to set up a generator with just some stone, redstone and coal. http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=Generator

Comment: that's a problem. I don't have a lot of coal left after smelting everything and caving takes up so much time it has gotten kinda boing for now, I actualy want to get things done

Comment: So i can now assume the 5 stacks of iron are actually bars instead of ore. A hint when playing a technic modpack is to keep as many ores as actual ores in the beginning. Just melt down the bare minimum you need untill you have some sort of ore dubbeling. (Macerator, grindstone, etc) Then again, coal is not terribly hard to get and you only need a little to get a whole lot of power.

Comment: yeah but it gets kind of boring all the caving

Comment: Don't forget that *most* things that accept Coal also accept Charcoal, which you can make large quantities of just by smelting logs. If you've got space for a few trees and some bonemeal lying around, you could relatively quickly make a stack or so of the stuff. That then either frees up your regular Coal if you can't use the Charcoal in the generator, or you can just use the Charcoal in it.

Comment: can i automate the process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always start with a generator on its own connected to a macerator and furnace. You'd be surprised how little power you need, probably a stack of coal is enough to get you through the early game, and it is very common in caves so it is fairly easy to get a large amount. My advice would then be to set up a nuclear reactor as fast as you can. As dangerous as it sounds, nuclear reactors are the best source of energy in industrialcraft and require the least amount of materials to maintain. Obviously the main detractor is the cost of making one, but with your materials at the moment I can't see it being too difficult. The clear danger here is a nuclear meltdown, which is absolutely devastating and will destroy everything around the reactor. However, using redpower or Project Red, you can use circuitry to make a meltdown an impossibility. You'll need a thermal monitor on the side of the reactor set to emit a redstone pulse when the reactor's core temperature reaches 500 degrees. Industrialcraft reactors are somewhat unrealistic in that their "operating" temperature (i.e. when all uranium cells are touching 1 coolant cell) is less than 100 degrees. From the thermal monitor connect redstone to a toggle latch, and that output back to the reactor. It should look something like this:[image]

That will ensure the reactor never overheats, as it will shut itself off as soon as the temperature inside gets too high. From there you can increase automatic maintenance, and potentially end up with a system like I've built in many worlds which will automatically produce a coolant cell whenever the reactor needs a new one. In terms of the materials used to run the reactor, all you need for a starting reactor is a uranium cell and a coolant cell, arranged something like this:
[image]

You will need to fairly regularly replace coolant cells when they run out, but that is all the maintenance you will need to do. If you need more power, all you need to do is add more uranium and coolant cells. In short, an amazing source of power with a low running cost.

NOTE: These screenshots are taken from tekkit rather than FTB, but the industrialcraft principles remain the same.

EDIT: By request, recipes and automation details.

EMPTY CELL:
[image]

REFINED URANIUM:
[image]

URANIUM AND COOLANT CELLS:
[image]
[image]

ADVANCED ALLOY:
[image]

INTEGRATED REACTOR PLATING:
[image]

REACTOR CHAMBER:
[image]

NUCLEAR REACTOR:
[image]

ADVANCED CIRCUIT:
[image]

And finally, some screenshots of a system automating the production of coolant cells:
[image]
[image]

This system will first detect when the reactor overheats. It then immediately shuts off the reactor, and a new coolant cell is put into the reactor from the chest in the corner. In the meantime, on the top of the building, redstone machines are fetching the parts for a new coolant cell; i.e. a cell and a water bucket. It then makes the cell using automatic crafting tables and feeds the water cell into the extractor (which can't be seen in the screenshots). This extractor then pumps the cell into the chest in the corner. During this time, a timer has been timing 10 seconds, after which time the coolant cell has been completed and the reactor restarts. The most complex part is manufacturing new coolant cells. It would be a simple process, were it not for the fact that each recipe produces 16 cells. On the top of the building, a counter is incremented every time a cell is made. After 16 cells have been produced, 4 tin ingots are pumped up from the ingots chest downstairs, ready to be crafted. The counter is then reset.

Comment: can you add some recepies and maybe (if possible) a way to atomaticly make colant/uranium cells for later (lets say project 2)

Comment: @codermaster certainly, I'll edit in some screenshots. It will look quite complex though, so I might have to go into some detail to explain it

Comment: that's okey take your time

Comment: @codermaster There you go :)

Comment: that's a big awnser good job, defenetly a thick, can you provide a world downolad so i can take a personal look?

Comment: @codermaster How would I go about that? Is there a website I can use?

Comment: www.mediafire.com is great for .rars like that, just put your world in a .rar file and upload it there, then give me the link

Comment: @codermaster Here you go: https://www.mediafire.com/?usgbvlj601xdvml

Bear in mind this is a tekkit classic world, so you'll have to open and play the world in tekkit classic.

Comment: okey now we both lerned something, you know how to share world files and i know how to succeed in playing FTB thanks bro

Comment: @codermaster no problem, glad i could help :D

Answer (score 3):

"Getting started" there are 4 basic energy generators you can use.

- Generator
- Water Mill
- Windmill
- Solar Panel

By far, the best one to "get started" with is the basic Generator. It only requires coal to run, and if you find a tree, you can start a tree farm, turn the wood into charcoal, and burn that.

The next best option would be the watermills. Sure, they don't provide much power, but they are low cost, and only require a pool of water to run. Setting up a puddle of water shouldn't be too hard. (If I need to instruct you on the building and usage of an infinite water source, we have bigger problems)

Up from that, the windmills provide more power per unit, however, setup and cabling can be a real pain. To be even slightly efficient, They need to be above level 70 (it might be higher, I can't quite remember), and that distance alone is enough for the cable leakage to render the power output next to nothing on anything lower than glass-fibre cables. Plus, as you said, it's hard to get a setup that looks halfway decent.

The last option is by far the best power source you can get. High power, renewable, so no wastage of resources, and you don't need much space to set them up, *and* they're upgradable (with the right modpacks). However, creation can be highly resource intensive, and can be a pain to try and set up right off the bat, and like you say, do actually require energy to make.

Comment: which one would you recomend in the situation I have (there are no trees in a desert, also litle water.)

Comment: If you have access to *any* water, you can make a pool using the infinite water trick, and setting up water wheels

Comment: okey, guess i should go caving for water then... (thats wierd)

Comment: @Ben I would like to correct you on the power loss in cable. In IC2 Experimental exists a Ultra LV cable or the Tin cable. Its loss is similar to glass fibre and it has a 5 EUP tolerance. Assuming that the windmill is set up to be at maximum safe EU (ie. no chance of breaking), Then the ULV cable would work.

Comment: how do I make this cable?

Comment: @codermaster It should be fairly simple, you can check the [wiki](http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=Tin_Cable) for the recipe(s)

Comment: that a dificult recepie for the begining I guess, I never heard of those machenes

Answer (score -2):

In the very early game, I use sugarcane. Put it into a compressor, then into a canning machine, then into an extractor, and you get biofuel.

Comment: that's a bit much. the canning machine is not realy "very early game"